# Meijer G explicit form

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

Can the following case of the Meijer G-function be expressed more explicitly (in terms of other special functions, but involving no infinite integrals)?
$$G_{3,4}^{3,2}\left(z\left|\begin{smallmatrix}1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{5}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},0\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)$$

Comment: @Iridescent What you have is correct for
$$G_{3, 4}^{1, 3} {\left( z \middle |
{1, \frac 2 3, \frac 2 3 \atop \frac 5 3, \frac 2 3, \frac 5 3, 0} \right)},$$
this is a different function.

Comment: Since we have a $\Gamma^2(5/3 + s)$ factor, the residue theorem will give an infinite sum of polygamma functions instead of gamma functions, Slater's theorem is not applicable. We can write the sum in terms of the derivative of ${_2 F_2}$ wrt one of the parameters.

Comment: @Iridescent The Mma convention for which object, though? When the G-function is written as in the question, there is no ambiguity about how it's defined.

Comment: @Maxim I found that I have mis-typed $G_{3,4}^{3,2}\left(z\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3} \\
 \frac{5}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$ as $G_{3,4}^{2,2}\left(z\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3} \\
 \frac{5}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$. My fault.

Comment: Since we have a Γ2(5/3+s) factor, the residue theorem will give an infinite sum of polygamma functions instead of gamma functions, Slater's theorem is not applicable. We can write the sum in terms of the derivative of 2F2 wrt one of the parameters.Since we have a Γ2(5/3+s) factor, the residue theorem will give an infinite sum of polygamma functions instead of gamma functions, Slater's theorem is not applicable. We can write the sum in terms of the derivative of 2F2 wrt one of the parameters. can you show me how?

Comment: Simplify the G-function to $G_{2, 3}^{2, 2}$. The residue at $s = -5/3 - k$ is
$$\frac {3 (k + 1) \psi(k + 1) z^{k + 5/3}} {(3 k + 5) k!} -
 \frac {3 (k + 1) z^{k + 5/3} \ln z} {(3 k + 5) k!} -
 \frac {6 z^{k + 5/3}}{(3 k + 5)^2 k!}.$$
The last two terms give ${_2 F_2}$ functions. For the first term, use
$$\psi(k + 1) =
\frac 1 {k!} \left. \frac d {da} (k + a)! \right\rvert_{a = 0},$$
then you get a derivative of a ${_3 F_3}$ function (the ${_3 F_3}$ can be expanded into two ${_2 F_2}$ functions).

Comment: @Maxim , how did you get the residue ? i have  $G_{2,3}^{2,2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int\frac{\pi\Gamma\left(s+\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\cos \pi \left(s+\frac{1}{6}\right)}z^{-s}ds$

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal That is not correct. $G_{3, 4}^{3, 2}$ has $3 + 2$ gamma factors in the numerator. One of those factors coincides with a factor in the denominator. There's still a repeated factor, giving double poles.

Comment: @Maxim, thanks. The integrand is $-\Gamma\left(s+\frac{5}{3}\right)^{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}-s\right)/sz^{-s}$, which gives the residue in your comment.